# how to set the CARBON_HOME system property to the created 'carbon_repo' directory,

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I tried this [post](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html) and I'm new to WSO2.I got problem to set the CARBON_HOME system property to the created 'carbon_repo' directory.

Actually,I wanna connect webapp from tomcat server to WSO2IS server as xacml engine.

Let me know if you could help me.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

First Download WSO2IS from here http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/

Under Entitlement you could see xacml related stuff like PAP,PDP,PEP

If you need connect webapp from tomcat server to WSO2IS server as xacml engine, you have to consume two services from webapp side 
1. EntitlementPolicyAdminService (CRUD operations for policies)
2. EntitlementService (Evaluate policies against PDP)

Alternatively If you would like use WSO2AS instead of tomcat, you can have entitlement filter which can be used as PEP 
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps/

Comment: Pls, I woud like to know the steps needed to connect webapp from tomcat server to WSO2IS server as xacml engine.
Let me know some guide or useful links. Thanks in advance!